# .Net Remoting - Reboot Server and get reboot status

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, reboot, .net-remoting

I have a client server set up between different computers on a network using .Net Remoting in C#.
The server runs in a service that starts up when the computer turns on.

I want the client to be able to restart the computer that is running the server service and receive a status if the restart succeeded or failed.

What is the best approach?

I found three different ways to reboot the server ([How to shut down the computer from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c)) :
1. command line shut down
2. user32.dll
3. WMI

Which Reboot method is better as far as getting Error statuses? Are there any other reboot methods I'm missing?

How Can I notify the Client about the reboot status?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your service a windows service? 
If so, then by checking if your service is up and running (ping the service / log the service Onstart method etc), the system reboot would have been successful.