# Shutdown or Reboot local machine on Button

Tags: c#

I've done a fair bit of googling and always seem to come back to the same solution, which just doesn't seem to work !

```
private void btnRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown.exe", "/r /f /t 00");
}

private void btnShutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown.exe", "/s /f /t 00");
}
```

The CMD appears for a brief second and then closes, without doing anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: it depends on the permissions the application has...

Comment: I am not sure, but `Shutdown.exe` might need to be `shutdown.exe`. Or maybe, that is only on Linux. Just a thought.

Comment: Well currently it's being tested under a domain administrator account.

Comment: And you've tried the command in cmd.exe itself and it works?

Comment: Yeah both commands work fine in cmd.exe with the same rights as the program itself.

Comment: Are you in Windows XP? Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724276/how-to-shut-down-from-c-process-startshutdown-not-working-in-windows-xp) the same?

Comment: Are you sure about account privilage use elevated vs to test your code

Comment: Yes, running as domain admin.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing "cmd /k" to the argument, i.e., "cmd /k shutdown.exe ..."? That should at least keep the command window open so you can see if shutdown.exe is displaying an error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit cleaner

```html
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int ExitWindowsEx(uint uFlags, uint dwReason);

ExitWindowsEx(1, 0); //this will cause the system to shut down.

ExitWindowsEx(2, 0); //this will cause the system to reboot.
```

Answer (score 0):

add these namespace to your code

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

And even it depends on what privileges you are assigned.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: @FrK reference the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

According to `shutdown /?`, you don't use slashes (/) but dashes(-).

Or, try to run `cmd.exe` with params `/c shutdown.exe /r /f /t 00`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing arguments with [ProcessStartInfo:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "/r /f /t 00";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer i got it from [HERE](http://www.geekpedia.com/code36_Shut-down-system-using-Csharp.html).It works for me.make sure to add a reference to `System.Management`

```
 using System.Management;

    void Shutdown()
    {
        ManagementBaseObject mboShutdown = null;
        ManagementClass mcWin32 = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
        mcWin32.Get();

        // You can't shutdown without security privileges
        mcWin32.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        ManagementBaseObject mboShutdownParams =
                 mcWin32.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");

        // Flag 1 means we want to shut down the system. Use "2" to reboot.
        mboShutdownParams["Flags"] = "1";
        mboShutdownParams["Reserved"] = "0";
        foreach (ManagementObject manObj in mcWin32.GetInstances())
        {
            mboShutdown = manObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", 
                                           mboShutdownParams, null);
        }
    }
```