# Where in the .net library can I find the functionality of 'InitiateSystemShutdownEx' Win32 function?

Tags: .net-3.5, winapi

In my application I want to shutdown and then restart the system after completion of some task.

There is a Win32 API function, `InitiateSystemShutdown()` for this purpose but where is this functionality encapsulated in the .net library?

```
System config:Win7/VS2008
```

update: Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

This does not exist in .NET to my knowledge. You can call it through P/Invoke though.