# How Reboot(Restart) vps with c# codes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vmware, reset, vps

I want to write some codes for a server that can Reboot(Restart) all vps s or one of them inside that server!
`VPS = VIRTUAL PRIVATE SERVER`
i have some questions about that:

1. how can i write those codes with c# codes for that job? and how can i recognize every vps inside server?
2. where should i run those codes ?   form a vps inside that server or
   another place?(want to access all vps s inside server using VMware)

really appreciate for viewing and help
stack is always my love

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. i edit my Q.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp) SO question

```
Process.Start("shutdown","/s /t 0");
```

(fits Windows machines only)

Now, combine this with a WCF service running on each VPS - you will have to code a management console (that you will use later on your computer, for instance) that will know (or, have features to add) a known VPS server (by, for example, it's IP address), and allow you to invoke this function on the remote VPSs

This way, you`ll have a service running on each VPS that allows you to sreboot, while having a management console to send shut-down directives to all or some of your servers from a remote computer

Comment: but is using WCF a good idea! i want to let users to call their own method when can n't login to own vps.  so can we use web service on every vps?

Comment: Yes you can install it on each VPS

Answer (score 1):

In combination with the process.Start solution form Shai you could use [psshutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx).

It does require that the boxes are domain joined, from the docs:

> ... and if you specify a wildcard (\*), the command runs on all computers
>   in the current domain

Comment: hi rene, does this tool work for remote server(vps)? can we use ip address as computer in it's command? (i test it, but show me it's help and nothing happens)