# Show shutdown dialog box from c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, system-shutdown

Is there a way to display the Windows shutdown dialog box from c#?

[image: Shutdown dialog box]

I found a command that I can use with System.Diagnostic.Process.Start

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe
```

But doesnt works on Windows 8

Comment: What does "doesn't works" mean?

Comment: the dialog doesnt appears on windows 8, but works normally on windows 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shutdown the computer from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27726215/294884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [shutdown.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) instead of trying to kill explorer.:

```
shutdown.exe /i /t 0
```

Comment: this dialog doesnt show the "switch user","sleep", "sign out" options

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried calling it from a C# process, but `shutdown /i` pulls a GUI on Windows 8 for me. Note that it isn't the same UI though.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but for those searching for an answer, at least in recent Windows systems (propably also in older ones) a good solution is to send a WM_CLOSE message to the window with classname "progman", this will trigger the default cancelable Windows shutdown dialog as shown in the screenshot above.
In plain C this would be:

```
SendMessage(FindWindow(_T("progman"), NULL), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```