# restarting my computer through a win forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to shutdown the computer from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp)

I want to bring up a restart computer message box after an event occurs in my Win Form application.
What command can I use to restart the computer if the user chooses Yes?

Comment: You may take a look at also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

You can [p/invoke `ExitWindowsEx`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ExitWindowsEx.html).

As noted, you'll need to call `AdjustTokenPrivileges` as well, since `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` is inactive by default.

A whole bunch of information available [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376883.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you should use WINAPI . the below function can do power task for you :

```
BOOL WINAPI ExitWindowsEx(
  _In_  UINT uFlags,
  _In_  DWORD dwReason
);
```

Note that this function is in user32.dll.
Simply to restart :

```
ExitWindowsEx(2,4);
```

Here is the full list of flags : [link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Now here is sample C# Code for this :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]

public static extern bool  ExitWindowsEx(uint uFlags,uint dWReason);


public static void Main()
{
  ExitWindowsEx(2,4);
}
```

Comment: ExitWindowsEx(2,4)? Magic number violation detected. Also, what is long int?

Comment: 4 is for EWX_FORCE and 2 is for EWX_REBOOT . david , plz correct me if there is any problem..

Comment: Second paramter is DWORD which is uint in C#. Your parameters should have real names. You need SetLastError = true in the DllImport attribute. And you must stop using magic numbers. Declare consts or enums.

Comment: thanks for that , I had a mistake in variable types mapping , and SetLastError has been updated... But I had not with you to not to use magic numbers , because here we want to do a single job and they will be addressed immediately by compiler . it is not an unsafe  code.I don't think enum will ran faster , but still for keeping the code managed , yes you are true. we should use enum or consts.

Comment: Speed is not important here. Have you any idea how many clock cycles will be consumed shutting that machine down?! What counts is readability. Write code that a human can read. Don't make the reader trek all the way to MSDN in order to understand your code.

Comment: in contrast , speed is important every where . you have dived too deeply, clock cycles , i think carbon di oxides that will be generated and the environment's pollution are your next hits. also human can use comments for that code .

Comment: So you think that using magic constants means faster code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("shutdown","/r /t 0");
```

Comment: No, don't do that. Always use the API. If you want to list the files in a directory, do you shell out to cmd?!!

Answer (score -1):

This particular solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/102583/1505128

```
using System.Management;

void Shutdown()
{
    ManagementBaseObject mboShutdown = null;
    ManagementClass mcWin32 = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
    mcWin32.Get();

    // You can't shutdown without security privileges
    mcWin32.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
    ManagementBaseObject mboShutdownParams =
             mcWin32.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");

    // Flag 1 means we want to shut down the system. Use "2" to reboot.
    mboShutdownParams["Flags"] = "1";
    mboShutdownParams["Reserved"] = "0";
    foreach (ManagementObject manObj in mcWin32.GetInstances())
    {
        mboShutdown = manObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", 
                                       mboShutdownParams, null);
    }
}
```