# Proper Approach for Invoking Tasks on a server

Tags: c#, service

I'm writing a C# application to automate a couple of common server admin tasks, and one of the tasks that I want to automate is shutting down or restarting the server (because a number of other applications have to be stopped in a certain order, and its a pain to do).

What the best way to invoke tasks on a server? What is the SAFE approach to server and service shutdown?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: There's a similar post.

Try that --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shutdown.exe` of Windows.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("shutdown","-s -t 10");
```