# Process started from a LocalSystem-owned ASP.NET site can't reboot local machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, process, reboot

I have an ASP.NET website that runs under LocalSystem. I am trying to reboot current machine by starting a new shutdown.exe process from a request thread like this:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "shutdown.exe",
                    Arguments = "-r -f",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

Process.Start(psi);
```

This fails with Access Denied error. I thought it was about missing privileges - but enabling it via C# code or PowerShell didn't help (based on answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-from-c-sharp)).  I also tried adding SYSTEM to the list of users/groups who have the permission to shutdown the system ([based on this](https://serverfault.com/questions/452767/allow-non-admin-user-to-shutdown-reboot-server-2012)).

So I tried running above code including UserName and Password to the ProcessStartInfo (a regular Adminsitrator account). I also made some checks to ensure that the process is actually executed under that user (not LocalSystem) - and it is. Reboot still doesn't work. Same happens when I try doing this with `powershell.exe` (and then cmdlet `Restart-Computer`) or with `cmd.exe` and `/c shutdown` as arguments. I tried this on 2 machines (one EC2 instance, one private server with fresh Windows Server 2016).

Now the most confusing part: as soon as I change my website app pool account to a regular Administrator user account instead of LocalSystem it starts to work. How is this possible? Is the parent-child process relation a problem? Is there any premission/privilege that I am missing when parent process is running as LocalSystem?