# How do I turn my pc off with C# in "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)"

Tags: c#

I'm making something to prank my friend when he finishes a game I'm making his computer will shut off. But I don't know where to start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

Process.Start("shutdown","/s /t 0");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex) to shut down the local computer.