# How to turn off computer with C?

Tags: c, windows

I want to shutdown PC with C without using system() functiom

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h> 
int main(){
    system("shutdown -s -t1");
}
```

I'd like to find better way.

Comment: Something like this. Just find the equivalent in c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-from-c-sharp

Comment: @drum: Bad dupe. He doesn't want to start shutdown.exe.

Comment: @Joshua why was it a bad dupe? One of the answers is to use the API ExitWindowsEx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shut down the Windows operating system using the function [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex) with the `EWX_SHUTDOWN` or `EWX_POWEROFF` flag.

However, as stated in the documentation, the calling process will require the `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privilege. See the documentation on how to allow the process to obtain that privilege.

Comment: There is way to add timer?

Comment: @Abdallah: A timer for what exactly? Do you want to initiate a shutdown when the timer reaches zero?

Comment: yes I want user to set time and when time be 0 computer shutdown

Comment: @Abdallah: See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-timers) for an overview of timers using the Windows API. The function `SetTimer` will probably be sufficient for what you want.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: There should be an API equivalent of `-t1`. I don't know it or I'd answer.

Comment: @Joshua: The function [`InitiateSystemShutdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdowna) has a `dwTimeout` argument, which may be the equivalent of the `-t1` command-line argument to `shutdown`. I am not sure.

Comment: Another option is to use `Sleep()` in the program.

Answer (score 2):

This is managed by the operating system, so you'll have to figure out how to do it on your OS.

It looks like you're using Windows, so you could try the Windows API's [System Shutdown Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-functions).